# QEMU can't run with --enable-trace-backends configured

Tags: trace, qemu

I complied QEMU using:

```
./configure --enable-kvm --target-list=x86_64-softmmu --enable-trace-backends=simple
```

Then I started a VM using simply just:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -nographic -vnc :1 -hda /home/cloud/ubuntu-rr.img -m 2048 -smp 4 --enable-kvm -smp 4 -monitor stdio
```

Nothing happened. I even couldn't call out the monitor with `Ctrl+A C`. It didn't work when I added `-trace events=/tmp/events`, either. What's wrong here? What should be the right way to utilize the QEMU tracing capability?
Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

File /tmp/events should be created before start of qemu. So please create at least empty file or fill it with events you are going to trace.